# Sending mail with SwiftMailer from a Symfony2 hosted on a OVH shared server

Tags: symfony, smtp, swiftmailer, mailgun, ovh

I'm desperatlly trying to send emails through SMTP with SwitfMailer on my Symfony2 app. It is hosted on an OVH shared server (pro2014 offer). But it's not working, I've tried A LOT of different solutions without success.

Of course in dev mode it's working (using my company SMTP). I've also tried solutions like Mailgun which are working fine everywhere except on OVH servers, for some reason.

In the meantime, I'm sending them via the PHP mail() (built in SwiftMailer), but that sucks. Like a lot.

And the OVH support is the worst I've seen, they doesn't help at all + they respond like once every 48 hours if you don't poke them through Twitter...

Does anyone here know how to do that?

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       smtp.mydomain.com
    mailer_user:       myemail@mydomain.com
    mailer_password:   mypassword
```

config_prod.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    auth_mode:  login
    port:       587
    encryption: ssl
```

config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get SwiftMailer bundle working on an OVH shared host I had to use:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: sendmail
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Bundle version: 5.4.8

No way to use smtp though, help is welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've a similiar problem. After trying with all the solutions (in my development and the production machine) I've tryied [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It works perfectly.

I think the problem is in SwiftMailer's code.

And you must change the port from 587 to 465.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it running using the following library : https://github.com/tehplague/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle

It uses the mailgun API calls instead of pure smtp protocol. This way, OVH won't block the communications.

The configuration is straightforward and is running out of the box (after installing the package Httplug as stated in the readme).